# Proof of the fact that one-form $\omega$ is exact $\Rightarrow$ $\int_{S^1} \omega =0.$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

I saw the proof of
$$\mathrm{one-form} \ \omega \  \mathrm{is \  exact} \Rightarrow \int_{S^1} \omega =0$$ where $S^1$ is an unit circle.

The proof is here.

---

Since $\omega$ is exact, there exists $f\in C^\infty$ s.t. $df=\omega.$

Then, $\int_{S^1} \omega=\int_{S^1}df=\int_{\partial S^1} f=0.$

---

I know that $\int_{S^1}df=\int_{\partial S^1}f$ is lead from Stokes, but
I don't know why $\int_{\partial S^1} f=0$ holds.

I want you to explain why this equality holds.

Comment: Have you tried to compute $\partial S^1$?

Comment: Perhaps, $\partial S^1=\emptyset$ ? But I don't think $\partial S^1=\emptyset$ holds since $\partial S^1$ seems to be a curved line segment.

Comment: boundary of a manifold is another manifold but of one less dimension. so dim of boundary of circle is ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly speaking, an interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$ has two boundary points $a$ and $b$. $S^1$ is like taking an interval and making it close back on itself, so the endpoints $a,b$ "become the same", so $S^1$ has no more boundary points. More formally, $S^1$ is a smooth manifold in the usual sense (every point of $S^1$ has an open neighborhood and a chart map, which maps it bijectively onto an open subset of $\Bbb{R}$). The fact that $S^1$ is a smooth manifold is surely something you must have seen much earlier than Stokes theorem.

Note that in a manifold $M$, possibly having boundary, if a point $p\in M$ is such that it has an open neighborhood along with a chart mapping to an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ (rather than the half space $\Bbb{H}^n$), then $p$ is NOT part of $\partial M$ (this is saying that the manifold boundary $\partial M$ the manifold "interior" are disjoint sets; this can be proven relatively easily using the inverse function theorem).

Hence, in the case of $S^1$, it has no boundary points (since we showed directly that every point is an "interior" point). Hence, $\partial S^1=\emptyset$.